# Android delete query database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i trying to delete query database in my app but i have a little problem.
so, in delete code i have 4 case :

1. database empty -> MESSAGE TOAST DATABASE EMPTY
2. txtfield empty -> MESSAGE TOAST TXTFIELD EMPTY
3. words in txtfield not found in DB -> MESSAGE TOAST word no found
4. deleted OK -> DELETE QUERY + TOAST NOTIFICATION

My problem is 3° case, I use an external method to verify if words exists in db!
this is code :

```
public boolean trovato(String n){

    boolean find = false;
    int k=0;

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME", null);
    int count= c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();

    String[] nomi = new String[count];


    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
       nomi[k]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname"));
       if(nomi[k].equalsIgnoreCase(n)){
           find = true;
           break;
       }else{
           k++;
       }


    }
    return false;
}

public void delete(View data){

    EditText delete=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdel);
    String delete2 = delete.toString();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME", null);
    int count= c.getCount();   

    if(count==0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DATABASE VUOTO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else if(delete.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"STRINGA VUOTA, RIPROVA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else if(trovato(delete.toString())){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NON ESISTE !!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE fname='"+delete.getText()+"'");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DELETE OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the function trovato(String n) you are always returning false.

Should be:

```
return find;
```

Intead of

```
return false;
```

Comment: i replace return but still not work.. method go to in 4° case!

Comment: You also should write delete.getText().toString() instead of delete.toString() to get the text written in the EditText

Comment: replaced with delete.getText().toStrig() but nothing changed!

Comment: Probably you are not using correctly the logic of the if statement. Shouldn't be 

`if(!trovato(delete.getText().toString())){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NON ESISTE !!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}`

I mean if the word is NOT found you show a message telling the word doesn't exists in this column of this table

Comment: THANK YOU @migue02 now work perfectly !
i deleted c.moveToFirst() because if database have just 1 item and i try to delete it, app crash!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer solved your question you should accept it as correct.